# react reload data with AJAX

Tags: reactjs

I have a series of React components loading data from HTTP service in `componentDidMount` as explained here http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html

```
<html>
<body>
  <script src="http://fb.me/react-0.13.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.13.0.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/jsx">
    var RandomGist = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function() {
        return {
          id: '',
          url: ''
        };
      },

      componentDidMount: function() {
        $.get(this.props.source, function(result) {
          var gist = result[Math.round(Math.random() * result.length)];
          this.setState({
            id: gist.id,
            url: gist.html_url
          });
        }.bind(this));
      },

      render: function() {
        return (
          <div>
            <a href={this.state.url}>{this.state.id}</a>
          </div>
        );
      }
    });

    var GistList = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
        return (<div>{[1,2,3].map(function() {
          return <RandomGist source="https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists" />;
        })}</div>);
      }
    });

    var RefreshableGistList = React.createClass({
      handleClick: function() {
        console.log("Click!");
      },

      render: function() {
        return (
          <div>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Refresh</button>
            <GistList />
          </div>
        );
      }
    });

    React.render(
      <RefreshableGistList />,
      document.body
    );
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

After click on Refresh button I would like to refresh gist from HTTP service. Problem is that `setState` and `forceUpdate` will not lead to that because getting data from HTTP service is done in `componentDidMount` as was explained in original react example.

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: Can you let me know if my answer helped?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like below. Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vyorj52s/3/).

```
var RandomGist = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href={this.props.url}>{this.props.id}</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var RefreshableGistList = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      gists: []
    }
  },

  fetchGist: function() {
    $.get("https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists", function(result) {
      var gist = result[Math.round(Math.random() * result.length)];

      this.state.gists.push({id: gist.id, url: gist.html_url})
      this.setState({
        gists: this.state.gists
      });
    }.bind(this));
  },

  generateRandomGists: function() {        
    [1,2,3].map(function() {
      this.fetchGist();
    }.bind(this));
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.generateRandomGists();
  },

  handleClick: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({gists: []})
    this.generateRandomGists();
  },

  render: function() {
    var gists = this.state.gists.map(function(gist) {
      return <RandomGist key={gist.id} url={gist.url} id={gist.id} />
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Refresh</button>
        <p />
        {gists}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(
  <RefreshableGistList />,
  document.body
);
```